# Including php files and using their variables

Tags: php

Is it possible to include different php files into a main file and use their variables? Lets say that I have 3 files:

file1.php:

```
$var1 = blabla...
$var2 = blabla...
$var1 = blabla...
```

file2.php

```
$var1 = blabla...
$var2 = blabla...
$var1 = blabla...
```

file3.php

```
$var1 = blabla...
$var2 = blabla...
$var1 = blabla...
```

And then a main file that includes the files above and displays their variables, via a for loop if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. This is very common. Just do not forget the `;` at the end of each variable.

```
<?php
require('file1.php');
require('file2.php');
require('file3.php');

// Do whatever you want to your variables here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can achieve this in a few ways: [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php).

Full PHP documentation: http://php.net/docs.php